# Postgres performance issue with query based on filter values

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-10

I am not an expert in Postgres, but I am trying to understand this strange behaviour and perhaps some of you might give me some insight.

Those are the tables and indexes involved

Tables

```
    CREATE TABLE swp_am_hcbe_pro.submissions
    (
        id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('swp_am_hcbe_pro.submissions_id_seq'::regclass),
        application_id bigint NOT NULL,
        transaction_names_id bigint NOT NULL,
        "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        submission_status character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        submission_type character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        exit_code character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        ignore_partner_status boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
        ignore_sell_partner_status boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
        ignore_exclusion_rules boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
        dpa_iban character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        dpa_bic character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        dpa_id bigint,
        dpa_blz bigint,
        dda_iban character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        dda_bic character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        dda_id bigint,
        dda_blz bigint,
        dda_sepa_mandate_ref character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        use_different_sepa_mandate character varying(34) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        use_manual_limit_extension boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
        use_automatic_limit_extension boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
        json_payload text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        final_timestamp timestamp without time zone,
        CONSTRAINT submissions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT submission_app_id FOREIGN KEY (application_id)
            REFERENCES swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications (id) MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT submission_transaction_names_id FOREIGN KEY (transaction_names_id)
            REFERENCES swp_am_hcbe_pro.transaction_names (id) MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION,
        CONSTRAINT chk_submission_status CHECK (submission_status::text = ANY (ARRAY['ERROR'::character varying, 'DENIED'::character varying, 'PROCESSED'::character varying, 'REJECTED'::character varying, 'PROCESSING'::character varying, 'SCHEDULED'::character varying]::text[])),
        CONSTRAINT submission_types CHECK (submission_type::text = ANY (ARRAY['AUTO'::character varying, 'MANUAL'::character varying]::text[]))
    )
    WITH (
        OIDS = FALSE
    )
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications_id_seq'::regclass),
    correlation_id character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    incoming_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    source_input character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    source_file_path character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    application_type character varying(127) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    loan_id bigint,
    vin character varying(17) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    cooperation_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    cooperation_id bigint,
    submitter_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    submitter_id bigint,
    dealer_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dealer_id bigint,
    dealer_ext_id character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    invoice_id character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stock_id character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    payment_term character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    reg_document_id character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    invoice_amount numeric(20,4),
    application_status character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dealer_group_id bigint,
    approver text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    approve_timestamp timestamp without time zone,
    payload text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    auto_resub_attempts integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    row_number bigint,
    email_sent boolean DEFAULT false,
    modified_date timestamp(6) without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    product_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    priority smallint,
    CONSTRAINT applications_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT chk_application_status CHECK (application_status::text = ANY (ARRAY['PROCESSED'::character varying, 'PROCESSING'::character varying, 'WAIT_NEXT_SUBMISSION'::character varying, 'WAIT_MANUAL_SUBMISSION'::character varying, 'WAIT_AUTOMATIC_SUBMISSION'::character varying, 'WAIT_IN_QUEUE'::character varying, 'SUBMISSION_NOT_FOUND'::character varying, 'WAIT_FOR_ASYNC_ACTIVATION'::character varying, 'WAIT_FOR_ASYNC_SHIPMENT'::character varying, 'WAIT_FOR_BOOKING_CONFIRMATION'::character varying, 'WAIT_FOR_ACTIVATION_CONFIRMATION'::character varying, 'REJECTED'::character varying, 'NOT_IN_QUEUE'::character varying, 'SCHEDULED'::character varying]::text[])),
    CONSTRAINT chk_source CHECK (source_input::text = ANY (ARRAY['LM'::character varying, 'KOSYFA'::character varying, 'SWPII'::character varying, 'ADM'::character varying]::text[]))
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE swp_am_hcbe_pro.transaction_names
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('swp_am_hcbe_pro.transaction_names_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    sub_name character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT transaction_names_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Indexes

```
CREATE INDEX submissions_app_id_asc_timestamp_desc_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.submissions USING btree
    (application_id, "timestamp" DESC)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX submissions_app_id_timestamp_trans_name_id_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.submissions USING btree
    (application_id, "timestamp", transaction_names_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX submissions_timestamp_asc_app_id_asc_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.submissions USING btree
    ("timestamp", application_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX application_correlation_id_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications USING btree
    (correlation_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX application_correlation_row_number_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications USING btree
    (correlation_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default", row_number)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX applications_application_status_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications USING btree
    (application_status COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX applications_invoice_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications USING btree
    (invoice_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX applications_vin_idx
    ON swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications USING btree
    (vin COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I have a the following view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW swp_am_hcbe_pro.application_list_simple AS
 WITH subm AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.application_id) s.application_id,
            s."timestamp",
            s.exit_code,
            s.transaction_names_id
           FROM swp_am_hcbe_pro.submissions s
          ORDER BY s.application_id, s."timestamp" DESC
        )
 SELECT app.id,
    app.correlation_id,
    app.source_input,
    app.source_file_path,
    app.application_type,
    app.loan_id,
    app.vin,
    app.cooperation_name,
    app.cooperation_id,
    app.submitter_name,
    app.submitter_id,
    app.dealer_id,
    app.dealer_name,
    app.dealer_ext_id,
    app.invoice_id,
    app.stock_id,
    app.payment_term,
    app.reg_document_id,
    app.invoice_amount,
    app.application_status,
    app.incoming_timestamp,
    app.dealer_group_id,
    app.approver,
    app.approve_timestamp,
    subm.exit_code,
    tn.name AS transaction_name,
    tn.sub_name AS sub_transaction_name,
    tn.id AS transaction_type_id,
    subm."timestamp" AS last_submission_timestamp,
    app.modified_date
   FROM swp_am_hcbe_pro.applications app
     LEFT JOIN subm ON app.id = subm.application_id
     LEFT JOIN swp_am_hcbe_pro.transaction_names tn ON tn.id = subm.transaction_names_id;
```

If I run this statement, the elapsed time is : `Execution time: 2481.333 ms`

```
explain analyze 
SELECT *, count(*) OVER () AS total FROM swp_am_hcbe_pro.application_list_simple 
WHERE INCOMING_TIMESTAMP >= '2021-11-08' AND INCOMING_TIMESTAMP <= '2021-11-09' 
ORDER BY APPROVE_TIMESTAMP DESC, INCOMING_TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
;
```

I got the following

```
"Limit  (cost=461799.85..461800.10 rows=100 width=490) (actual time=2473.878..2474.618 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=461799.85..461803.13 rows=1311 width=490) (actual time=2473.877..2474.612 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: app.approve_timestamp DESC, app.incoming_timestamp DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 112kB"
"        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=458791.38..461749.74 rows=1311 width=490) (actual time=2471.792..2473.247 rows=1620 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=458791.38..461720.25 rows=1311 width=482) (actual time=2456.132..2470.895 rows=1620 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (subm.transaction_names_id = tn.id)"
"                    CTE subm"
"                      ->  Unique  (cost=0.43..333656.64 rows=129297 width=31) (actual time=0.036..1846.992 rows=645062 loops=1)"
"                            ->  Index Scan using submissions_app_id_asc_timestamp_desc_idx on submissions s  (cost=0.43..329433.26 rows=1689349 width=31) (actual time=0.033..1621.049 rows=1699582 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=125133.09..128058.44 rows=1311 width=459) (actual time=2456.083..2470.337 rows=1620 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (subm.application_id = app.id)"
"                          ->  CTE Scan on subm  (cost=0.00..2585.94 rows=129297 width=106) (actual time=0.038..2135.256 rows=645062 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=125116.71..125116.71 rows=1311 width=361) (actual time=237.582..238.310 rows=1620 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 483kB"
"                                ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..125116.71 rows=1311 width=361) (actual time=11.959..236.468 rows=1620 loops=1)"
"                                      Workers Planned: 2"
"                                      Workers Launched: 2"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on applications app  (cost=0.00..123985.61 rows=546 width=361) (actual time=2.880..97.484 rows=540 loops=3)"
"                                            Filter: ((incoming_timestamp >= '2021-11-08 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (incoming_timestamp <= '2021-11-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 214530"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.29..1.29 rows=29 width=31) (actual time=0.033..0.033 rows=29 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on transaction_names tn  (cost=0.00..1.29 rows=29 width=31) (actual time=0.011..0.015 rows=29 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.587 ms"
"Execution time: 2481.333 ms"
```

If I run this one,  which only changes the date filter, it takes **`Execution time: 365817.271 ms`**

```
explain analyze 
SELECT *, count(*) OVER () AS total FROM swp_am_hcbe_pro.application_list_simple 
WHERE INCOMING_TIMESTAMP >= '2021-11-09' AND INCOMING_TIMESTAMP <= '2021-11-10' 
ORDER BY APPROVE_TIMESTAMP DESC, INCOMING_TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
;

"Limit  (cost=462844.68..462844.69 rows=1 width=490) (actual time=365809.554..365810.419 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=462844.68..462844.69 rows=1 width=490) (actual time=365809.553..365810.411 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: app.approve_timestamp DESC, app.incoming_timestamp DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 125kB"
"        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=334656.77..462844.67 rows=1 width=490) (actual time=365806.595..365808.483 rows=2140 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=334656.77..462844.65 rows=1 width=482) (actual time=2094.856..365793.839 rows=2140 loops=1)"
"                    CTE subm"
"                      ->  Unique  (cost=0.43..333656.64 rows=129297 width=31) (actual time=0.036..1771.818 rows=645068 loops=1)"
"                            ->  Index Scan using submissions_app_id_asc_timestamp_desc_idx on submissions s  (cost=0.43..329433.26 rows=1689349 width=31) (actual time=0.034..1563.614 rows=1699595 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1000.00..129187.86 rows=1 width=459) (actual time=2094.836..365762.361 rows=2140 loops=1)"
"                          Join Filter: (app.id = subm.application_id)"
"                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1380443382"
"                          ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..124985.71 rows=1 width=361) (actual time=8.475..33.996 rows=2140 loops=1)"
"                                Workers Planned: 2"
"                                Workers Launched: 2"
"                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on applications app  (cost=0.00..123985.61 rows=1 width=361) (actual time=1.809..103.597 rows=713 loops=3)"
"                                      Filter: ((incoming_timestamp >= '2021-11-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (incoming_timestamp <= '2021-11-10 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 214359"
"                          ->  CTE Scan on subm  (cost=0.00..2585.94 rows=129297 width=106) (actual time=0.030..125.740 rows=645068 loops=2140)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using transaction_names_pkey on transaction_names tn  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=2140)"
"                          Index Cond: (id = subm.transaction_names_id)"
"Planning time: 0.414 ms"
"Execution time: 365817.271 ms"
```

I can't really understand why this is happening. I tried also to run queries with filters getting more than one date ( like one week, one month ) and all of them works fine.

I vacuum the affected tables, even though there were not so many rows. What else can I check ?

If you need further information, don't hesitate to ask me

**UPDATE**

If I change the query to this, using `to_timestamp` over the string, then it works. But why it does work in all the other cases and not in this one ? Why is always happening with the current date ?

```
explain analyze
SELECT * FROM swp_am_hcbe_pro.application_list_simple 
WHERE INCOMING_TIMESTAMP >= to_timestamp('2021-11-09 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
AND INCOMING_TIMESTAMP <= to_timestamp('2021-11-10 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
ORDER BY APPROVE_TIMESTAMP DESC, INCOMING_TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 ;
```

I obtain the following

```
"Limit  (cost=463151.72..463151.97 rows=100 width=481) (actual time=2743.036..2743.923 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=463151.72..463153.01 rows=517 width=481) (actual time=2743.035..2743.918 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: app.approve_timestamp DESC, app.incoming_timestamp DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 121kB"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=460200.05..463126.79 rows=517 width=481) (actual time=2730.684..2741.744 rows=2382 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (subm.transaction_names_id = tn.id)"
"              CTE subm"
"                ->  Unique  (cost=0.43..333658.84 rows=129297 width=31) (actual time=0.020..1669.678 rows=645311 loops=1)"
"                      ->  Index Scan using submissions_app_id_asc_timestamp_desc_idx on submissions s  (cost=0.43..329435.46 rows=1689349 width=31) (actual time=0.019..1476.827 rows=1700028 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=126539.56..129464.91 rows=517 width=458) (actual time=2730.642..2740.999 rows=2382 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (subm.application_id = app.id)"
"                    ->  CTE Scan on subm  (cost=0.00..2585.94 rows=129297 width=106) (actual time=0.023..1924.458 rows=645311 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=126533.10..126533.10 rows=517 width=360) (actual time=736.655..737.534 rows=2382 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 4096 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 864kB"
"                          ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..126533.10 rows=517 width=360) (actual time=18.882..734.265 rows=2382 loops=1)"
"                                Workers Planned: 2"
"                                Workers Launched: 2"
"                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on applications app  (cost=0.00..125481.40 rows=215 width=360) (actual time=15.908..610.513 rows=794 loops=3)"
"                                      Filter: ((incoming_timestamp >= to_timestamp('2021-11-09 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (incoming_timestamp <= to_timestamp('2021-11-10 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 214359"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=1.29..1.29 rows=29 width=31) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=29 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on transaction_names tn  (cost=0.00..1.29 rows=29 width=31) (actual time=0.012..0.018 rows=29 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.370 ms"
"Execution time: 2751.279 ms"
```

So, the question remains

Why this query takes 360 seconds ?

```
SELECT * FROM swp_am_hcbe_pro.application_list_simple 
    WHERE INCOMING_TIMESTAMP >= '2021-11-09' AND INCOMING_TIMESTAMP <= '2021-11-10' 
    ORDER BY APPROVE_TIMESTAMP DESC, INCOMING_TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
    ;
```

But this one takes 3 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM swp_am_hcbe_pro.application_list_simple 
WHERE INCOMING_TIMESTAMP >= to_timestamp('2021-11-09 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
AND INCOMING_TIMESTAMP <= to_timestamp('2021-11-10 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
ORDER BY APPROVE_TIMESTAMP DESC, INCOMING_TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 ;
```

In any other case, it works no matter I use or not `to_timestamp`. Just a remark, I removed the `count(*) over()` in my last update to show that is not relevant, so still the problem remains.

Thank you for your support

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we to know your table and index definitions. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones, I would be glad to add the table and index definition, but in this case what is the relationship when the query works in any scenario except in one ? If you look up the plans, they are almost identical. So the index or tables are working in any scenario where I use a filter for more than  one date. I updated the question showing that the same query works with `to_timestamp` for the filter of the current date

Comment: `Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1380443382"` is the difference. [plus only one index is used; maybe because only one usable index is found?]

Comment: @wildplasser, I got that, but still it should happen not matter what the range dates are, isn't it? So, if I use `to_timestamp` it works for this scenario, and any other. If I don't use it, it works for all scenarios except the current date

Comment: `Join Filter: (app.id = subm.application_id)"` <<-- [crystal ball: no usable indexes available]

Comment: I will update the indexes and table definition

Comment: pg_version() below ~10? -->> try to get rid of the CTE and the DISTINCT

Comment: `SELECT current_setting('server_version_num');` is 100016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid the (non-indexed) CTE scan by using a (TEMP) view instead of a CTE [I also replaced the `DISTINCT ON(...)` BY a `NOT EXISTS(...)` ]:

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vsubm AS
         SELECT -- DISTINCT ON (s.application_id)
         s.application_id
            , s.ztimestamp
            , s.exit_code
            , s.transaction_names_id
        FROM submissions s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM submissions nx
                WHERE nx.application_id = s.application_id
                AND nx.ztimestamp > s.ztimestamp
                )
        -- ORDER BY s.application_id, s.ztimestamp DESC
        ;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW application_list_simple2 AS
 SELECT app.id
    , app.correlation_id
    , app.source_input
    , app.source_file_path
    , app.application_type
    , app.loan_id
    , app.vin
    , app.cooperation_name
    , app.cooperation_id
    , app.submitter_name
    , app.submitter_id
    , app.dealer_id
    , app.dealer_name
    , app.dealer_ext_id
    , app.invoice_id
    , app.stock_id
    , app.payment_term
    , app.reg_document_id
    , app.invoice_amount
    , app.application_status
    , app.incoming_timestamp AS INCOMING_TIMESTAMP
    , app.dealer_group_id
    , app.approver
    , app.approve_timestamp AS APPROVE_TIMESTAMP
    , vsubm.exit_code
    , tn.name AS transaction_name
    , tn.sub_name AS sub_transaction_name
    , tn.id AS transaction_type_id
    , vsubm.ztimestamp AS last_submission_timestamp
    , app.modified_date
   FROM applications app

     LEFT JOIN vsubm ON app.id = vsubm.application_id
     LEFT JOIN transaction_names tn ON tn.id = vsubm.transaction_names_id
        ;

-- EXPLAIN
-- explain analyze
SELECT *
        -- , count(*) OVER () AS total
FROM application_list_simple2
WHERE INCOMING_TIMESTAMP >= '2021-11-08' AND INCOMING_TIMESTAMP < '2021-11-09'
ORDER BY APPROVE_TIMESTAMP DESC, INCOMING_TIMESTAMP DESC
-- LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

---

WRT the observed behaviour:

- selecting a date-range *at the edge of time* may cause a different plan to be generated. Different from a timespan *in the middle*
- *maybe* the statistics for today's records are still incomplete (the statistics collector could be lagging behind)
- bad plans (lots of hash-joins and seq-scans) may be caused by lack of statistics, lack of indexes, or `random_page_cost` set to high.
- The row-sizes for the tables are rather large. Maybe some normalisation is needed, especially for the `applications` table.
- mixing timestamps with/without time zone could cause some confusion. [general advise: always use timestamps **with** time zone]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will test your approach and let you know the results. Although it does not explain the strange behaviour with the filtering.

Comment: I tested your approach and indeed it  is faster than the original one. Tomorrow I will test your code in the morning using the same filter for current date to verify what happens. What I realized is when you use the current date in the filter, postgres changes uses a nested loops instead of a hash join.

Comment: just a question: `explain analyze` collect statistics over the tables and indexes involved in the query ?

Comment: No. `EXPLAIN` only shows the query plan; `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows the plan **after executing** it, annotated with the observerd metrics. `ANALYZE` collects statistics on tables.

Comment: I am implementing your approach based on two views, instead of one. I am thinking in changing SET STATISTICS to 1000 for the columns involved in the joins and the filter. Again, thank you so much for your support

Comment: The two views was just my lazy way of converting the CTE. It could also be expressed as (a subquery) part of the original view.

Comment: I tried that, but I got better performance using two views. I don't honestly know why